# Module parse failure with @hapi/joi dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, joi

Im getting the following issue:

```
./node_modules/@hapi/joi/lib/types/object/index.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (254:64)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|                     if (pattern.regex ?
|                         pattern.regex.test(key) :
|                         !pattern.schema._validate(key, state, { . 
   ...options, abortEarly:true }).errors) {
| 
|                         unprocessed.delete(key);
```

Also an error message that indicates the following:

```
Cannot find file 'Applications/IntelliJ/IDEA.app/contents/bin/././node_modules/@hapi/joi/lib/types/object/index.js'
```

Dependency im using:

```
 "dependencies": {
 "@hapi/joi": "^15.0.3",
```

Also I've got the module installed and when I navigate to it, the index.js file is in there.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Though what I did is completely remove that part of code from '/hapi/joi/lib/index.js' file which temporarily fixes the issue.. Also had to remove some piece of code from '@hapi/hoek/lib/deep-equal.js'. Also my guess is that some particular loaders are missing in the webpack-config file, however I most definitely want to avoid running an eject.